# Add new object key value to laravel db query results

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-collection

I have a query that returns a collection object like so:

```
 Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
(
[items:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => App\Http\Models\LabTestRequests Object
            (
                [table:protected] => lab_test_requests
                [primaryKey:protected] => request_id
                [connection:protected] => 
                [keyType:protected] => int
                [perPage:protected] => 15
                [incrementing] => 1
                [timestamps] => 1
                [attributes:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [status_category] => Old Results
                    )

                [original:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [status_category] => Old Results
                    )

                [relations:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [hidden:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [visible:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [appends:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [fillable:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [guarded:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => *
                    )

                [dates:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [dateFormat:protected] => 
                [casts:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [touches:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [observables:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [with:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [exists] => 1
                [wasRecentlyCreated] => 
            )

        [1] => App\Http\Models\LabTestRequests Object
            (
                [table:protected] => lab_test_requests
                [primaryKey:protected] => request_id
                [connection:protected] => 
                [keyType:protected] => int
                [perPage:protected] => 15
                [incrementing] => 1
                [timestamps] => 1
                [attributes:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [status_category] => Pending
                    )

                [original:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [status_category] => Pending
                    )

                [relations:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [hidden:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [visible:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [appends:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [fillable:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [guarded:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => *
                    )

                [dates:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [dateFormat:protected] => 
                [casts:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [touches:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [observables:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [with:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [exists] => 1
                [wasRecentlyCreated] => 
            )

        [2] => App\Http\Models\LabTestRequests Object
            (
                [table:protected] => lab_test_requests
                [primaryKey:protected] => request_id
                [connection:protected] => 
                [keyType:protected] => int
                [perPage:protected] => 15
                [incrementing] => 1
                [timestamps] => 1
                [attributes:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [status_category] => Done
                    )

                [original:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [status_category] => Done
                    )

                [relations:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [hidden:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [visible:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [appends:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [fillable:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [guarded:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => *
                    )

                [dates:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [dateFormat:protected] => 
                [casts:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [touches:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [observables:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [with:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [exists] => 1
                [wasRecentlyCreated] => 
            )

        [3] => App\Http\Models\LabTestRequests Object
            (
                [table:protected] => lab_test_requests
                [primaryKey:protected] => request_id
                [connection:protected] => 
                [keyType:protected] => int
                [perPage:protected] => 15
                [incrementing] => 1
                [timestamps] => 1
                [attributes:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [status_category] => Non-Negative
                    )

                [original:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [status_category] => Non-Negative
                    )

                [relations:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [hidden:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [visible:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [appends:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [fillable:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [guarded:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => *
                    )

                [dates:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [dateFormat:protected] => 
                [casts:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [touches:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [observables:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [with:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [exists] => 1
                [wasRecentlyCreated] => 
            )

        [4] => App\Http\Models\LabTestRequests Object
            (
                [table:protected] => lab_test_requests
                [primaryKey:protected] => request_id
                [connection:protected] => 
                [keyType:protected] => int
                [perPage:protected] => 15
                [incrementing] => 1
                [timestamps] => 1
                [attributes:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [status_category] => Test Complete Pending Review
                    )

                [original:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [status_category] => Test Complete Pending Review
                    )

                [relations:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [hidden:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [visible:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [appends:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [fillable:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [guarded:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => *
                    )

                [dates:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [dateFormat:protected] => 
                [casts:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [touches:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [observables:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [with:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [exists] => 1
                [wasRecentlyCreated] => 
            )

    )

  )
```

In my view im iterating through each and showing the status_category value - what im trying to accomplish is to check if a specific status_category value does not exist then to add it to the end. 
I have tried doing:
        $categories->prepend('test', 'status_category');

but that doesnt add it like the object above and therefore my view will throw an error. Any ideas on this?

Comment: So, if status_category does not exist then you want to show a default value. Am I understanding it right?

Comment: Yes if Test is not part of the list of status_categories then i want to add it

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the laravel collection map function for set value in object key value.

```
$categories = $categories->map(function ($item, $key) {
     $item->status_category = "test"; 
     return $item;
});
```

Comment: With this solution your issue is resolved or still you facing issue?

Comment: Do you get chance in look into this?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve via

1) Laravel Collection [map()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-map)

```
$labTestRequests = $labTestRequests->map(function($labTestRequest){
    if(!isset($labTestRequest->status_category)) {   // checking if a key exist
        $labTestRequest->status_category = "default";
    }
    return $labTestRequest;
});
```

2) Using a simple `null coalesce` operator i.e. `??`. What it does is if a given variable **does not exists** or **is null** then use the given **default** instead. In your view you can write like this

```
$labTestRequest->status_category ?? 'default'
```